# Why am I getting java.lang.NullPointerException for a String array?

Tags: java, arrays, error-handling, null

Not exactly sure why I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException for the String array? I looked for hours but can't find any problem. Please help

```
private String[] stringList;
int j = 0;
StringClass stringRef = new StringClass();

while (//As long as there is string available from what I am reading in)
{
        str = //String read in;
        stringRef.setString(str);
        stringList[j] = stringRef.returnString(); //Shows that this line is the error
        j++;
}
```

Here is the class:

```
public class StringClass {

   private String stringNew;

   public void setString(String newStr){
      stringNew = newStr;
   }

   public String returnString(){
      return stringNew;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `public class StringClass {...}`? Either way, I hope that's not how you have named your class!

Comment: And `stringList` would be `null` at the point it throws the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You did not use a `List` even though it is in the name of your variable `stringList`.  Lists will dynamically resize, so you do not have to declare the initial size at compile time.

Here is your code with my suggested changes:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

...

private List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
int j = 0;
StringClass stringRef = new StringClass();

while (//As long as there is string available from what I am reading in)
{
        str = //String read in;
        stringRef.setString(str);
        stringList.add(stringRef.returnString()); //Shows that this line is the error
        j++;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. If I would like to print out the first or the second that was added to the list, how would you index it with the list?